# Need help getting a function that removes a string from an array to work

Tags: c++

I have a function look that looks through a string array and returns a value that then gets called into the Delete function. Which from that value gets deleted.

I put up a lot of the code here, just look at the operator+ function implemented to the Delete function. And see their use in the main function.

The operator + adds strings into an array, it takes up four spots int the array.
The Delete function is supposed match the first word in the first string to Delete it, but it's telling me there is no word found.

```
#include    <iostream>
#include    <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
class AR

{

public:

AR(); 

AR(int );

AR(const AR &); 
~AR(){delete []con;} 
bool Full(){return counter==cap;}       
int Look(const string & );

AR & operator+(const string );   

void Delete(const string &);          

AR & operator=(const AR &);

friend ostream & operator<<(ostream &, AR &);

friend ifstream & operator>>(ifstream & , AR &);

void Double_size();    


private:

string *con;

int counter;

int cap;

};




#include "ar.h"


AR::AR()
  {



    counter = 0;                    //initializing state of class
    cap = 2;

    con = new string[cap];

}

AR::AR(int no_of_cells)   
  {


    counter = 0;
    cap = no_of_cells;
    con = new string[cap];


}

AR::AR(const AR & Original)  
{

    counter = Original.counter;
    cap = Original.cap;

    con = new string[cap];

    for(int i=0; i<counter; i++)
    {
        con[i] =Original.con[i];
    }

}



ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, AR & Original)  
{
        for(int i=0; i< Original.counter; i++)
    {
        out<<"con[" << i <<"] = "<< Original.con[i]<<endl;
    }
    return out;
}

AR & AR::operator=(const AR &rhs)
{   
    if(this != &rhs)
    {
        delete []con;
        counter= rhs.counter;
        cap = rhs.cap;
        con= new string[cap];
        for(int i=0;i<counter;i++)
        {
            con[i]= rhs.con[i];
        }
    }

    return *this;
}



ifstream & operator>>(ifstream & in, AR & Original)
{

    Original.counter = 0;

    while(!in.eof() && Original.counter<Original.cap)  
    {
        in>>Original.con[Original.counter];
        (Original.counter)++;
    }

    return in;
}

AR & AR::operator+(const string word)  
{


        if(Full())    //conditions if array is full or empty
        {
            Double_size();    // capacity get's doubled
        }
    con[counter]=word;
    counter++;

    return *this;
}

void AR::Double_size()
{
        cap *= 2;
    string *tmp = new string[cap];

    for(int i=0;i<counter;i++)
    {
        tmp[i]= con[i];
    }

    delete []con;
    con = tmp;

}


int AR::Look(const string & word)
{
    for(int i=0;i<counter;i++)
    {
        if( con [i] == word)
            return i;


    }
    return -1;

}

void AR::Delete(const string & word)
{


    int loc = Look(word);

    if (loc == -1)
    {
        cout<<"word not found\n";
    }

    else
    {

        for(int i=0;i<counter-1,i++;)
        {

            con[i]= con[i+1];
        }
    }
}







#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "ar.h"
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    cout<<"invoking the default constructor"<<endl;
    AR myAr;
    cout<<"Output after default constructor called\n";
    cout<<myAr<<endl<<endl;

    cout<<"invoking the explicit-value constructor "<<endl;
    AR yourAr(5);
    cout<<"Output after explicit-value constructor called\n";
    cout<<yourAr<<endl<<endl;


    cout<<"invoking the copy constructor "<<endl;
    AR ourAr = myAr;
    cout<<"Output after copyconstructor called\n";
    cout<<ourAr<<endl<<endl;


    cout<<"testing overloaded operator= with chaining as a member "<<endl;
    AR X, Y, Z;

    X = Y = ourAr;
    cout<<"Output after operator= called\n";
    cout<<X<<endl<<endl;


    cout<<"testing overloaded operator<< overloaded as a friend with chaining "<<endl;
        cout<<X<<Y<<Z;
    cout<<endl<<endl;

    cout<<"testing overloaded operator+ as a member function with chaining, Double_size "
        <<" and Full."<<endl;
    AR theirAr(1);
    theirAr + "Overload the +" + " operator as a member function " + "with chaining to add a string " + "to an Arrary object.";

    cout<<theirAr<<endl<<endl;


    cout<<"testing Delete and Look.  <<endl;

    theirAr.Delete("XXXXXX");
    theirAr.Delete("Overload");
    cout<<"Output after Delete and Look called\n";
    cout<<theirArray<<endl<<endl;



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please clean your code so it's easier to read.

Comment: Just a tip to make better questions: be as concise as you can. Don't post 200 line code just to show 30 of it.

Comment: When you write code you should start with something small and simple, add complexity a little at a time, get every step to work perfectly before proceeding to the next, and develop new functions *in isolation* before adding them to the whole. If you run into a problem, prepare a [minimal complete example](http://sscce.org) before you ask for help. This code is much too long and doesn't compile, and if you keep doing code dumps like this I for one will start voting to close them.

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for a COMPLETE string equals to "Overload" here

```
theirAr.Delete("Overload");
```

but you have the string `"Overload the +"` stored in the array of string so the comparation between them is false, because `"Overload"` and `"Overload the +"` are differents. If you want to find a subString inside a string, then you need to use something like `std::string::find` in the following way:

```
int AR::Look(const std::string & word)
{
    int result = -1;
    for(int i=0; i<counter; ++i)
    {
        if( con[i].find(word) != std::string::npos)
            result = i;
    }
    return result;

}
```